# How many articles for Sitemap XML?

Tags: xml, sitemap, google-search-console

I have a news website that contains `25,042` URLs. I've used this code to create a dynamic sitemap which contains articles in a week and submitted it to Google Webmaster everyday.

```
//Sitemap.xml articles list
$articles = Collection::factory('Article','db')->getArticlePublishedByParams(
    [
        'distribution_date' => [
            '$lte' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:00'),
            '$gte' => strtotime('-7 days', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00'))
        ]
    ],
    [
        'sort' => [
            'distribution_date' => -1
        ]
    ]
);
```

Everything is fine but I was wondering how many articles should I put into the sitemap? Should I put all `25,042` URLs into sitemap.xml?

I think if I do that, my website will get more Google indexes.

Any idea?